# Passing glob command from Popen to terminal

Tags: python, linux, bash

I need to be able to run an FIO file from within a python script. The file I'm running will have the .fio extension, but I have no control over the full filename. How would I use the Popen or call functions in python to pass the terminal this command:

```
fio *.fio
```

?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module:

```
import subprocess
import glob

cmd = ['fio'] + glob.glob('*.fio')
subprocess.Popen(cmd, ...)
```

This also allows you to see the name of the file or files, since `cmd[1:]` will contain the expanded name of any file that matched `*.fio`.

Answer (score 1):

Globbing is a shell function, so you can use `shell=True` and have the shell do it.

```
subprocess.Popen("fio *.fio", shell=True)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. Follow up question: How could I discover what the name of the file actually was?

Comment: Try `echo *.fio` if you want to use the shell, or `glob.glob('*.fio')` to get it more directly.